# Spinnaker Jira Stage. How to get created jira ticket as a pipeline artifact?

Tags: jira, spinnaker, artifact

I am using jira spinnaker stage to create a ticket in my project. I want to reference that newly created jira ticket later in my pipeline to leave comments on it as a I progress further along the pipeline.

I looked for documentation on this and couldn't find anything pointing at what values should be populated in the Produce Artifact section:

[image]

Does anyone know? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use [Pipelines expressions](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/#dynamically-skip-a-stage) and obtain the value of the created Jira ID. 
example `${#stage("Jira create ticket")["JIRA_ID"]}`

Then you can refer to that ID in the artifact section.